# SQL1273N - Missing log file "S0000000.LOG" in database partition "0"

Tags: db2, db2-luw, disaster-recovery

I'm getting this error when trying to connect to a DB2 Database. This error started after the OS restarted.

```
db2 => connect to cm
SQL1273N An operation that reads the logs in database "CM" cannot proceed 
due to a missing log file "S0000000.LOG" in database partition "0" and log 
stream "0".
```

Any help are welcome.

Comment: Well, I'd the file missing.

Comment: Can you please execute "db2 get db cfg for your_database | grep LOG" and update the question.

Answer (score 0):

> This error started after the OS restarted.

Apparently that is not the only thing that happened. Db2 attempts to perform crash recovery during the database activation when you try to connect to it, but at least one of the log files is missing.

Either find the missing log files and copy them where they belong, or restore the database from a backup.

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I have not backed up this database - this is a development environment, not a significant one.
The logs exist in the C:\DB2\NODE0000\SQL00002\LOGSTREAM0000 folder. I tried removing them ) from the folder (I thought they were corrupt) and they weren't automatically created. I did the same on SAMPLES and the files were recreated.
It's not the first time the same problem happens, but I can't understand what happened

Answer (score 0):

I have got the similar symptoms few years back, restarting operating system and database required to provide some logs. I have copied logs from archive disk and database got successfully recovered.

Can you please check the DB CFG values for parameters LOGSECOND and LOGARCHMETH1.

If LOGSECOND=-1 and LOGARCHMETH1=DISK:/ in some rare situations where there is long lasting transaction and database already archived transaction log to archive location, but when database is restarted like operating system restart, then database expects this log file to be in transaction log location.

If LOGSECOND=-1 then make sure that you force out of database long lasting applications.